# Using accessor to print out data in two formats

Tags: c++, accessor

I'm trying to use an accessor function to print out/return data from a class, after manipulating it. I am currently getting an error:

> expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have pointer-to function type

The `forceType`, `xArg` and `yArg` parameter values are taken from a file that is being read in `main()`. I need to be able to print out the original `xArg` and the `pol` (which is modified `xArg`).

I'm very new to all of this, so would really appreciate some help.

```
Force::Force(char fType, float xAr, float yAr)
{
    forceType = fType;
    xArg = xAr;
    yArg = yAr;    
}

float Force::GetXArg () const {
    if (forceType == 'c'){
        return xArg;
    }
    else {
        float pol = sqrt((xArg)(xArg)+(yArg)(yArg));
        cout << pol << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no implicit multiplication in C++. Add some `*`'s.

Comment: `(xArg)(xArg)` is not a valid expression.  Do you want them multiplied?  If so `sqrt(xArg*xArg + yArg * yArg)` is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(xArg)(xArg)` looks *kind of* like a function call `f(xArg)`.

The real problem is that in C++, unlike in math, there is no implicit multiplication. You have to be explict - `xArg*xArg + yArg*yArg`.

Comment: oh wow, thank you! no idea how i missed something that simple